# How to use Mongoose/Mongodb with node.js- passport authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I am building my first full stack node.js application and I want to use passport for authentication. I came across a tutorial for passport that stored the users info in a users array.

passport-config.js file:

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

function initialize(passport, getUserByEmail, getUserById) {
  const authenticateUser = async (email, password, done) => {
    const user = getUserByEmail(email)
    if (user == null) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'No user with that email' })
    }

    try {
      if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
        return done(null, user)
      } else {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Password incorrect' })
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return done(e)
    }
  }

  passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, authenticateUser))
  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.id))
  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    return done(null, getUserById(id))
  })
}

module.exports = initialize
```

server.js file

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  require('dotenv').config()
}

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const passport = require('passport')
const flash = require('express-flash')
const session = require('express-session')
const methodOverride = require('method-override')

const initializePassport = require('./passport-config')
initializePassport(
  passport,
  email => users.find(user => user.email === email),
  id => users.find(user => user.id === id)
)

const users = []

app.set('view-engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(flash())
app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
app.use(methodOverride('_method'))

app.get('/', checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.render('index.ejs', { name: req.user.name })
})

app.get('/login', checkNotAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.render('login.ejs')
})

app.post('/login', checkNotAuthenticated, passport.authenticate('local', {
  successRedirect: '/',
  failureRedirect: '/login',
  failureFlash: true
}))

app.get('/register', checkNotAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.render('register.ejs')
})

app.post('/register', checkNotAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
    users.push({
      id: Date.now().toString(),
      name: req.body.name,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: hashedPassword
    })
    res.redirect('/login')
  } catch {
    res.redirect('/register')
  }
})

app.delete('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.logOut()
  res.redirect('/login')
})

function checkAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next()
  }

  res.redirect('/login')
}

function checkNotAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return res.redirect('/')
  }
  next()
}

app.listen(3000)
```

I am using a mongoDb database for my application and want to store the users in my database. I have made the necessary changes in the register route and I can successfully store the data in my database.

```
app.post('/register', checkNotAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
      
      const users = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: hashedPassword
    })
      await users.save()
      res.redirect('/login')
               
     }
     
     catch(err){
         console.log(err)
         res.redirect('/register')     }
})
```

The problem is when I try to login with the stored user's data I keep getting the following error.

Error: data and hash arguments required
at Object.compare (C:\AIT715\reactlogin\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:208:17)
at C:\AIT715\reactlogin\node_modules\bcrypt\promises.js:29:12
at new Promise ()
at Object.module.exports.promise (C:\AIT715\reactlogin\node_modules\bcrypt\promises.js:20:12)
at Object.compare (C:\AIT715\reactlogin\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:204:25)
at Strategy.authenticateUser [as _verify] (C:\AIT715\reactlogin\passport-config.js:14:24)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)

I have tried making the following changes to the passport-config.js file but it hasn't worked.

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const User = require('./models/user')

function initialize(passport, getUserByEmail, getUserById) {
  const authenticateUser = async (email, password, done) => {
    const user = await User.find({email:email});
    console.log(user);
    if (user == null) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'No user with that email' })
    }

    try {
      if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
        return done(null, user)
      } else {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Password incorrect' })
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return done(e)
    }
  }
```

Also when I console.log(user) I can the data but when I try console.log(user.email) I get undefined. Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong here? or what changes do I need to make to the passport-config file to make this work. Any leads or help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @fabian . I have made sure that the passwords are indeed raw and hashed. I have a feeling that something is broken in my code after const user = await User.find({email:email});  The reason is that I have tried testing the other conditions such as giving in a user that doesn't exist and I still get the same response.

Answer (score 1):

```
const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
```

Make sure you are giving raw password and hash password. This will return a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

In case, anyone is looking at this in the future; Using findOne instead of find worked for me.

```
const user = await User.findOne({email:email});
```